# Java Android AsyncTask + mysql connection

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-asynctask

I have a problem, I am trying to connect to a MySQL database using `AsyncTask`. I put the connection code in the button event but it gives me error,

Here is the code:

```
    package com.example.mysqlconnect;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;





import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://cool/app";
  private static final String user = "user";
  private static final String pass = "password";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                Connect();
            }
        });
    }

  TextView tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  private class Connect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
      String response = "";

      try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
          // System.out.println("Database connection success"); 

          String result = "Database connection success\n";
          Statement st = con.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from users");
          ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

          while(rs.next()) {
            result += rsmd.getColumnName(1) + ": " + rs.getInt(1) + "\n";
            result += rsmd.getColumnName(2) + ": " + rs.getString(2) + "\n";
            result += rsmd.getColumnName(3) + ": " + rs.getString(3) + "\n";
          }
          tv.setText(result);
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          tv.setText(e.toString());
      }
    return response;   


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        tv.setText(result);
    }
  }

  public void Connect() {
    Connect task = new Connect();
      task.execute();

    }
}
```

I'm new to AsyncTask, can someone help me finding the errors?

Here's the logcat:

```
    10-23 19:08:41.168: W/dalvikvm(1514): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb40ca180)
10-23 19:08:41.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1514): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 19:08:41.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1514): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mysqlconnect/com.example.mysqlconnect.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 19:08:41.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
10-23 19:08:41.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
10-23 19:08:41.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-23 19:08:41.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
10-23 19:08:41.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-23 19:08:41.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-23 19:08:41.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-23 19:08:41.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 19:08:41.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-23 19:08:41.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-23 19:08:41.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-23 19:08:41.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1514): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 19:08:41.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1794)
10-23 19:08:41.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at com.example.mysqlconnect.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:51)
10-23 19:08:41.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-23 19:08:41.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
10-23 19:08:41.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
10-23 19:08:41.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1514):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
```

I removed the second on create and now i get this error in logcat:

```
10-23 19:10:29.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1565): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 19:10:29.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1565): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mysqlconnect/com.example.mysqlconnect.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Done, i've added the logcat...

Comment: Why there are two super.onCreate(), remove second super. and setContent..

Comment: Look at my answer, your "tv" is null. And it is because you initiate it outside onCreate. You can only declare it outside, and initiate it inside onCreate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is: `TextView tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);` because it is declared outside of `onCreate`.

So this is what you have to do, declare `TextView tv;` above `onCreate`. Then inside `onCreate` you add `tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);`

And remove the duplicate of:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: Ok, now with that it work... but i have one other problem, why when i click the button the asynctask don't start?

Comment: Have you logged it? Put a log inside your method "Connect()", "doInBackground()" and "onPostExecute" and tell me what it logs.

Comment: Log.d("yourTag", "text"); and then check in Logcat for your specific tag what it says. Put different text in each one of them, so you know where u are.

Comment: The log tell that the button click call public void Connect() {
   Connect task = new Connect();
      task.execute();
      Log.d("Connect","first" );
    }
But it block here and it wont to start the background process...

Comment: I think you need to implement onPreExecute in your AsyncTask as well.

Comment: http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/

Comment: I added  protected void onPreExecute() {
     
        super.onPreExecute();
  
        tv.setText("connecting");
        Log.d("post","pre execute");
  
     }
but it wouldn't continue, and the logcat is showing nothig...

Comment: Very strange mate :S it should work. I'm going to sleep now, post here if you find anything else and I'll answer you tomorrow. Good luck

Comment: Did you follow exact the link I gave u?

Comment: Hope yes, i added The preexecute above The do inbackgroud, is that OK?

Comment: Don't know, code seems fine to me. But maybe something else your doing wrong, try add the super on those methods as well.

Comment: and change your method name of Connect() to connect(). Nothing to do with this, but it can be confusing when you have the same name for your AsyncTask.