# I can't get my android app to connect to an external database on my xampp server

Tags: java, android, jdbc, xampp

I have been trying to make an app to connect to a database running on a xampp server. I have made a java application to do this in the past, I used JDBC to connect to the database. I checked to see if this was applicable to android, I found a tutorial where the JDBC was used on android but it did not work for me. My other two attempts at connecting to the database was, the HttpURLConnection and HttpClient methods. The solutions I have found from browsing, have not solved my issue yet. The two solutions I tried were, editing the xampp httpd-xampp.conf to allow any connections. The second was adding a user for the phone in the PhpMyAdmin privilages section. I don't know what other options I can try. Can anyone give me any advice to this issue. A normal java application can connect to the server with no problems, I can also access the server on my phones web browser. It's just the app that can't establish a connection.

**EDIT** Following a question I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037730/java-android-asynctask-mysql-connection). I tried connecting to my database with the JDBC using an AsyncTask the user who posted that question didn't have trouble making a connection. So I don't see where I am going wrong with my code here if the full class

**App code**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewCarsEntered extends Activity implements OnTouchListener 
{

private TextView displayCars;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_cars_entered);
    displayCars = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.carSpaceDisplay);
    displayCars.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

/**
 * Connect to the database 
 * @return String
 */
private class ConnectToDatabase extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) 
    {
        String response = " ";
        String total = "";
        int rowCounter = 0;

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://server_ip:3306/dbname", "username", "password");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT VehicleDetected FROM entry");

            while(resultSet.next())
            {
                rowCounter++;
            }

            total = Integer.toString(rowCounter);

            response = " I am connected to the database";       
            Log.d("DebugTag", response);

        }catch(Exception e){
            response = "Couldn't get a connection";
            Log.e("Error_Tag", response);
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        displayCars.setText(result);
    }   
}

/**
 * Constructor for the AsynchronousTask inner Class
 */
public void ConnectToDatabase()
{
     ConnectToDatabase connect = new ConnectToDatabase();
     connect.execute();
}


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{
    ConnectToDatabase();
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.view_cars_entered, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Does your app has internet permission declared on the manifest? What happens when you run your code? Do you get a response from your DB or you get an exception?

Comment: Define "did not work for me." That said, if you're using Android 4.x any attempt to access the network from the device on the main UI thread will result in a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Might want to examine your logcat.

Comment: Did not work as in, When I run the app on my device, my error log message is always being displayed."Log.e("error_tag", "Can't establish a connection to the database");". I have the internet permission added in the manifest aswell

Comment: I searched for     NetworkOnMainThreadException in the logcat and nothing came up. I am using 4.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Got the app working. I used the HttpClient approach. I added that code into a AsyncTask inner class. On the PHP side instead of giving the ip of the pc running the server, I just used local host. here is the code below hopefully this will help someone in the future.

**connect_to_database.php**

```
<?php

//Parameters for connecting to the database
$hostname = "localhost";
$database_name = "dbname";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";

//Connection String. If it fails causes error message
$connection = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

//Access the database
mysql_select_db($database_name, $connection);

/*Query to get number of cars and execute the query
 *If there is a problem with the query an error is returned */
$get_number_of_cars = "SELECT VehicleDetected FROM entry ";
$query_runner = mysql_query($get_number_of_cars) or die(mysql_error());
$counter = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_runner))
{
    $counter++;
}

echo $counter;
?>
```

**ViewCarsEntered.java**

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewCarsEntered extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
{

private TextView displayCars;
private TextView displaySuggestionMessage;
private HttpPost post;
private HttpResponse httpResponse;
private HttpClient client;
private ProgressDialog dialog = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_cars_entered);
    displayCars = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.carSpaceDisplay);
    displaySuggestionMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.carSpaceSuggestionsBox);
    displayCars.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

/**
 * Connect to the database 
 * @return String
 */
private class ConnectToDatabase extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) 
    {
        String serverResponse = " ";

        try
        {
            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            post = new HttpPost("http://server_ip/folder_for_php_script/connect_to_database.php");
            httpResponse = client.execute(post);

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            serverResponse = client.execute(post, responseHandler);

        }catch(Exception e){
            serverResponse = "Could not connect to Database";
            Log.e("Error_Tag", e.toString());
        }
        return serverResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        displayCars.setText(result);

        int responseCheck = Integer.parseInt(result);

        if( responseCheck <= 7 )
        {
            displayCars.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            displaySuggestionMessage.setText("It is ok to park in the main car park");
        }

        else if( responseCheck <= 11)
        {
            displayCars.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            displaySuggestionMessage.setText("You may want to try the B block");
        }

        else if( responseCheck >= 12)
        {
            displayCars.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            displaySuggestionMessage.setText("Consider Alternate Parking");
        }
    }   
}

/**
 * Constructor for the AsynchronousTask inner Class
 */
public void ConnectToDatabase()
{
    ConnectToDatabase connect = new ConnectToDatabase();
    connect.execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{
    ConnectToDatabase();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.view_cars_entered, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```