# is it possible to use jdbc driver on android?

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, user-interface

i can use jdbc driver with java gui but i cant use on android.i added mysql connection jar  and i use same connection informations(ip-name-pass).compiler dosnt give me error but it isnt working.is it possible to use jdbc on android?

in these code i never take "bağlantı başarılı" message

```
try {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "driverbağlantısı", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


                try {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                               "başlıyor", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://000.000.000.000/sdsa" , "root", "pass");
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                               "bağlantı başarılı", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                               "bağlantı başarısız", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();


        };


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "driver hatası"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: What about address 000.000.000.000 ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't working"? Do you get an exception? If so what exception exactly?

Comment: Where is located MySQL database?

Comment: @DmitryTsechoev it ok,i didnt write my informations.

Comment: on internet,vps @DmitryTsechoev

Comment: @PatrickHuy its going to the last catch "driver hatası"

Comment: Embedding the root password in your application is asking for your database server to be hacked.

Comment: You must write some Internet-address instead 000.000.000.000.

Comment: @DmitryTsechoev it isnt 000.000.000.000,i just write that,in real code its true.

Comment: @user3368157 Ok. Could you edit your question and add the complete exception message (possibly including stacktrace?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use jdbc connections on android.But the thing is you have to use `AsynTask` to  communicate with the `MySQL`. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037730/java-android-asynctask-mysql-connection). All the best :)